# InputMismatchException help, how to override?

Tags: java

So, I've been stuck on this problem for a while and do not understand why my code is not working. I'm trying to teach myself Java and looking at conditionals and loops right now. So the program basically is just trying to read in an integer (int num), but if anything besides an int is entered have it ask for correct input and give a message describing what has been entered. I hope that makes sense. I'm not entirely sure if this is correct but I'm also very new to this and have been struggling to figure out what I'm missing.

Here's the code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopPrac{

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            
        int num;
        boolean bool = false;
            
        System.out.println("Enter an Integer: ");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
            
        while(bool = false){    
            System.out.println("Enter an Integer: ");
            num = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
                
            if(scan.hasNextDouble()){
                System.out.println("Error: Index is Double not Integer.");
            }
            if(scan.hasNext()){
                System.out.println("Error: Index is String not Integer.");
            }
            if(scan.hasNextInt()){
                bool = true;
            }   
        }

        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace and the input you are use

Comment: `while(bool = false)` looks suspicious. You are *reassigning* `bool` instead of comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception `InputMismatchException` is because you ask the scanner to scan the next integer `scan.nextInt()` but it found double or string or something else so it throws an exception that this input is not a integer.

So you can fix your code by first ask the scanner is next input is integer or not `scan.hasNextInt()`, it it int scan it, else check if it double or any type to print error message

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter an Integer: ");
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int Index = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Index = " + Index);
    }
    else if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Index is Double not Integer.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error: Index is not Integer.");
    }
}
```